# Import data into excel from a webpage written in script

Tags: java, javascript, html, excel, import

I am trying to import live data from a webpage. However the webpage seems to be written in a script so I can't seem to be able to import the data into excel.
I am trying to run a macro. I did a search and found the following thread very useful;
[Import Data in Excel from a table created by a script in a WebPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039677/import-data-in-excel-from-a-table-created-by-a-script-in-a-webpage) (first answer)

but I don't have enough knowledge to tweak the code for my website?

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I would have to do this, my first question would be: Is there not another possibility to get the data directly? The server, that generate this HTML and JavaScript, must also get the data from elsewhere. So the best solution would be, if you could get the data form the same sources as the server. For example as XML. There are many straightforward solutions to get XML into Excel.

If this is not possible, then you will need a browser, that can render this script generated HTML. Fortunately with VBA you can automate the InternetExplorer.

To use this code, you have to provide some references in VBA. To do so:

- In VBA Editor select Tools/References from the menu bar.
- select "Microsoft Internet Controls"
- select "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library" or insert a UserForm into
  your VBA project
- select "Microsoft HTML Object Library"

The code belongs into a Module.

```
Option Explicit
Private oBrowser As InternetExplorer

Private Sub openBrowserAndLogin()
 Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer

 With oBrowser
  .Visible = True
  .navigate "http://rtm-test.nexala.com/fleet"

  Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
   DoEvents
  Loop

  On Error Resume Next
  With .Document.forms("spectrumLoginForm")
   .elements("j_username").Value = "test"
   .elements("j_password").Value = "***"
   .submit
  End With
  On Error GoTo 0

  Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
   DoEvents
  Loop
 End With
End Sub

Private Function takeSnapshot() As String
 Dim oTables As IHTMLElementCollection
 Dim oTable As IHTMLElement
 Dim sTableHTML As String
 With oBrowser
  Set oTables = .Document.getElementByID("fleetGrid").getElementsByTagName("table")
  Set oTable = oTables(1)
  sTableHTML = oTable.innerHTML
 End With
 takeSnapshot = sTableHTML
End Function

Private Sub getWebContentOnTime()
 Dim oHTMLDoc As IHTMLDocument
 Dim oTable As IHTMLElement
 Dim oTR As IHTMLTableRow
 Dim oCell As IHTMLTableCell
 Dim oWS As Worksheet
 Dim oClip As DataObject
 Dim sTableHTML As String
 Dim sDivClassName As String
 Dim aClassProps As Variant
 Dim dTime As Double
 Dim lRows As Long
 Dim lCols As Long
 Dim lColsRow As Long


 sTableHTML = takeSnapshot()

 Set oHTMLDoc = New HTMLDocument
 oHTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = "<html><table id=""t1"">" & sTableHTML & "</table></html>"

 Set oTable = oHTMLDoc.getElementByID("t1")
 lRows = 0
 lCols = 0
 For Each oTR In oTable.Rows
  lColsRow = 0
  For Each oCell In oTR.Cells
   sDivClassName = oCell.FirstChild.className
   aClassProps = Split(sDivClassName, "_")
   If aClassProps(0) = "fleet" Then
    On Error Resume Next
    oCell.Style.backgroundColor = aClassProps(1)
    oCell.Style.Color = aClassProps(2)
    On Error GoTo 0
   End If
   lColsRow = lColsRow + 1
  Next
  If lColsRow > lCols Then lCols = lColsRow
  lRows = lRows + 1
 Next

 Set oClip = New DataObject
 oClip.SetText "<html><table>" & oTable.innerHTML & "</table></html>"
 oClip.PutInClipboard

 Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 oWS.Paste Destination:=oWS.Range(oWS.Cells(1, 1), oWS.Cells(lRows, lCols))

 dTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
 Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTime, _
        Procedure:="getWebContentOnTime", _
        Schedule:=True

End Sub

Public Sub getWebContentMain()
 Dim dTime As Double

 Call openBrowserAndLogin

 dTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
 Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTime, _
        Procedure:="getWebContentOnTime", _
        Schedule:=True

End Sub
```

Startpoint is getWebContentMain.

This code will start the Internet Explorer with the security settings for the "Web content zone" which are set in "Internet Options". So there must be enabled "Active Scripting" to run the JavaScript on the web page.

After 10 seconds it will take the first snapshot from the continuously changing web page. Then it will take a snapshot every 5 seconds.

The code ends with a error, if you close the browser, but the last snapshot retains. It also ends, if you close the workbook.

In some circumstances may be your IE is not flagging `.Busy` and `.ReadyState` correct after the POST request with the credentials. Then you get a error if the code tries to get the `.Document`. In this case increase the time value for the first Application.OnTime command.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: I understand. Can you delete your post or edit out the login details? Thanks