# Import Data in Excel from a table

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, import

The VBA below imports one month of the Dow Jones Industrial Average data to ExceL. Is there a way to modify the code to import one year of data?

[Import Data in Excel from a table....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039677/import-data-in-excel-from-a-table-created-by-a-script-in-a-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it and here's why: that code pulls a static copy of the page http://www.investing.com/indices/us-30-historical-data. But to go from the default "Daily" to "Yearly" you need to click a drop down. If clicking the drop down changed the URL it would work but it doesn't. Your options are:

1. Use a different data source such as this one https://www.quandl.com/data/YAHOO/INDEX_DJI-DJI-Dow-Jones-Industrial-Average
2. Dynamically open Interet Exporer and manipulate it from VBA (I wouldn't recommend this).