# Importing table to Excel that was generated by a script from a webpage

Tags: html, excel, vba, import, powerquery

I've been trying to import the following table into Excel

www.bursamalaysia.com/market/securities/equities/indices/

I've tried PowerQuery, Data Tab "From Web" etc. From my research, I've come to believe that the reason that Excel cannot "see" the data is because it was dynamically generated with Javascript.

I would appreciate any help trying to get the table into excel via PowerQuery or even a VBA script.

I saw something similar [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039677/import-data-in-excel-from-a-table-created-by-a-script-in-a-webpage) and modified it as follows but I am getting an empty table.

```
Sub Bursa_Indices()

Dim xmlHttp As Object
Dim TR_col As Object, TR As Object
Dim TD_col As Object, TD As Object
Dim row As Long, col As Long

Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
xmlHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/securities/equities/indices/", False
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
xmlHttp.send

Dim html As Object
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.ResponseText

Dim tbl As Object
Set tbl = html.getElementById("bm_indices_prices_table")

row = 1
col = 1

Set TR_col = html.getelementsbytagname("TR")
For Each TR In TR_col
    Set TD_col = TR.getelementsbytagname("TD")
    For Each TD In TD_col
        Cells(row, col) = TD.innerText
        col = col + 1
    Next
    col = 1
    row = row + 1
Next
```

End Sub

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the VBA script you are running and the errors you are getting.

Comment: The error from the VBA script is the one at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039677/import-data-in-excel-from-a-table-created-by-a-script-in-a-webpage

I think I've figured out the error. The url has changed from http to https. I am trying to modify it to my url but just getting blanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

It looks quite straightforward using Power Query / Get & Transform.  I used New Query / From Web / paste that URL / choose the table named "RSS Feeds".

Comment: The table that I need is the "Indices" table. Somehow, I am not able to get there with a Power Query. Thanks.

Comment: The data from that table is exactly what I'm looking at in Power Query.

Comment: I'm trying it again right now and I am only able to see "Document". Yesterday was a market holiday and I was able to see both "Document" and "RSS Feeds". However, I'm not able to get the "Indices" table at all. I am wondering if the table rendering time is a factor.

I am using: Microsoft Office 2013 with Power Query 2.39.4526.123 32-bit

Comment: Thanks. I've updated Power Query to the latest version: 2.40.4554.161 32-bit
After retrying with the link and selecting RSS Feeds, the only table loaded was:
"Media Releases" "Subscribe"

Unfortunately, the Indices table was not loaded.

Comment: I'm now getting the same result. You probably need to use a specialised web scraping tool.